Artinian Gorenstein subrings with same socle degree
I am looking for examples of Artinian Gorenstein subalgebras with the same socle degrees.
More precisely, let $A$ be an Artinian Gorenstein $k$-algebra (with $k$ algebraically closed of characteristic $0$) with standard grading (generated in degree $1$) and socle degree, say $d$. Let $B \subsetneq A$ be an Artinian Gorenstein subalgebra of $A$. Is it possible that $B$ has the same socle degree $d$?
Similarly, if $B$ is a quotient of $A$ and $B$ is an Artinian, Gorenstein $k$-algera. Is it possible that $B$ has the same socle degree $d$?

Let $A=k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$. If $\mathrm{char}(k)\neq 2$, then the
subalgebra generated by $x+y$ is Gorenstein with the same socle
degree. On the other hand, for any graded Artinian algebra $A$, any
nonzero ideal $I$ intersects the socle notrivially. Hence if $A$ is
Gorenstein then $I$ contains the socle (say of degree $d$), so $A/I$ has no elements of degree $d$.

Thank you! Why should any nonzero ideal intersect the socle non-trivially? Could you please give a hint/reference.

Hint: the socle of $I$ is contained in the socle of $A$.
